# INSERT new record into MS access using java and SQL query INSERT INTO

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I want to add a new record to access database,, but the SQL query is not applying it,, here is my Code in which i am adding data!!

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton b=(JButton)e.getSource();
    if(b==c.t.addR){
        String aa=Integer.toString(55);
        String t=c.t.titlefield.getText();
        String d=c.t.datefield.getText();
        String p=c.t.progressfield.getText();
        String pr=c.t.priorityfield.getText();
        String s="Open";
        System.out.println(t+"\t"+d+"\t"+p+"\t"+pr+"\t"+s); //error is here
        try {
            c.b.st.executeQuery("INSERT into Records (TaskID,Title,Deadline,Progress,Priority,Status) VALUES("+aa+"','"+t+"','"+d+"','"+p+"','"+pr+"','"+s+")");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the error i am getting

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   '55','a','1','1','high','Open'.   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)  at
>   Listener.actionPerformed(Listener.java:27)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: `"...VALUES("+aa+"','"+t+"','"+d+"','"+p+"','"+pr+"','"+s+")"` Please let me extend that for you: `"...VALUES(aaa', 'ttt', 'ddd', 'ppp', 'prpr', 'ss)` Does that look odd to you?

Comment: Your code is unsafe against SQL attacks. Make use of [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to mitigate SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has to be happening on this line:

```
c.b.st.executeQuery("INSERT into Records (TaskID,Title,Deadline,Progress,Priority,Status) VALUES("+aa+"','"+t+"','"+d+"','"+p+"','"+pr+"','"+s+")");
```

And looking at it, it will be because you don't have an openning and closing quote around your parameters?  Try:

```
c.b.st.executeQuery("INSERT into Records (TaskID,Title,Deadline,Progress,Priority,Status) VALUES('"+aa+"','"+t+"','"+d+"','"+p+"','"+pr+"','"+s+"')");
```

Comment: thanks,,, error removes, But There is Another little problem i am facing,,, I have to manually Set the "TaskID",, Which is my primary key, i want it to be automatically generated, so i have selected its type, to "AutoNumber" in java,,,, But here when i skip the "TaskID",, Error generated which says "Primary key cannot be null" Plz propose a solution!!!

Comment: @MasoodFarooq should it be set to an autonumber in Access not in java.

Comment: would u mind to share me the ms.access to java  library? i think i'm gonna try the smallest one from your case. @MasoodFarooq